# Microsoft Graph Application Permissions - Restrict read/write to specific file/folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, umbraco

I can't seem to find anywhere where I can restrict access for an application to read/write to a specific file/folder.

Within the permissions its just for all. -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

I have am Umbraco website, where on form submissios, it would write to a file in Sharepoint, however giving the application access rights to all files isn't entirely safe. If in the event the website gets compromised, they may be able to access files from an organisations Sharepoint.

If this cannot be achieved at all, are there any possible workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good way to achieve this (yet) using application permissions (i.e. app-only permissions).

If the application is using delegated permissions (in other words, if the application is acting on behalf of the signed-in user), then the application can only access files which the user is also authorized to access. This is still not perfect, but it does reduce the scope of access when compared to every file in every site collection.

For various reasons (including security and stability), it is *not* recommended that applications use a non-interactive username/password flow to access Microsoft Graph (or any API).

> That said, as a last resort you *might* consider using [this flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) with a dedicated non-privileged user account that *only* has access to the site collection/files in question. Only explore this option if you are completely confident that the application in question is highly trusted and secure (sicne the application will technically be able to do anything that user account can do, which in many cases includes a bunch of things you don't want anything other than very highly trusted apps to be able to do).

Comment: I think this might be the way to go unfortunately... However, is there a way to authenticate a user via C#? In PostMan I can if I set the username and password and I can get the token, but in C# I'm using ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder and there are no options for usernaeme/password? Unless there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Using MSAL, your only option is [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication). (Again, and for the record: _not_ recommended.)

Comment: Yep just did that right now and getting a 404 where it worked with the application.
I had another issue but that was resolved by changing the default client type to a public client

Comment: You might want to confirm using an interactive experience (e.g. [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge)) that the user really does have access.

Comment: Its great we are thinking alike haha. I was using PostMan, and the files don't exist, but in Graph Explorer they do. Which is baffling. I can go to my drive in both of them, but when I try to get children via postman, I get an empty array, but a list of items via the graph explorer

Comment: I've compared the Access Token, and it seems the Graph Explorer has more rights over than the one I have used to create from https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication Any ideas?

Comment: And as for delegated permissions, I've just set it as Files.ReadWriteAll

Comment: Compared the tokens using https://jwt.io/ and the graph explorer has more scopes set than the one generated by the code. I was using .default, but when changing the scope, it throws an error as it requests for the admin to grant permission, but within the portal, it states admin consent isn't required?

Comment: Even if the permission doesn't normally require admin consent, user consent might be disabled entirely (or restricted), which would not allow the user to grant that permission themselves. You probably want to grant tenant-wide admin consent for the required delegated permissions (be sure to include `User.Read` and `offline_access`), then use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` when requesting the access token. Also, use conditional access (or require user assignment) to ensure only the expected user (the one you're using as a service account) can "sign in" to this app.

Comment: I have got then admin to grant access for it and now it works. Going to check if its possible to access other files/folders as a sanity check

Answer (score 0):

@Philippe Signoret provided me with the right solution.

To give a breakdown of what needs to be done and how to overcome possible issues, please read the following:

- Current solution is to use the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), using delegated permissions for a single user (in my case a dedicated single user) to have files restricted
- Make sure to check the permissions set in your Portal and grant any permissions that have't been granted already
- You will need to use/update your code to use the [Username Password Authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication)
- Use both [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and [Postman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman) to test your connection and calls
- For further debugging where it works on one and not the other, copy and paste the tokens and compare using https://jwt.io/ as this will distinguish the differences between the permissions set (as MS Graph Explorer will have more rights if you allow it, which I completely forgot about)